# If I shut down my console from in-game, will games saved to Cloud Storage be uploaded?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

Fiddling around under Storage settings, I noticed a new *Cloud Storage Console Copy* listing under System Items on my hard drive.

I'm assuming with this, that games stored in the Cloud Storage are saved locally here first and then uploaded, but when do the games get uploaded to the Cloud? I typically just shut down the console from in-game when I'm done playing, and am wondering if this will cause a problem.  Is shutting down immediately after saving a safe option to take if saving games to the cloud? Are the games uploaded immediately or at some later time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Xbox 360 doesn't actually shut down when you ask it to - there's even an option in the Preferences pane where you can tell it to stay on to finish downloads after you tell it to shut down.  I believe that the cloud storage saves work the same way.

[Some people](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/live_update_fall_2011/f/2362/p/156251/814714.aspx#814714) are reporting that their fans are running for an additional time after they tell the system to shut down.  This delay reportedly went away when the cloud sync options were disabled.

When you're in this "network sync state" the LEDs on the box are generally off, and the display is blank, but sometimes the fan keeps running (depending on your Xbox revision, I believe).

So as long as you're shutting it down properly (via the Xbox menu or the power button) I believe your cloud storage items will be properly sync'ed.

Comment: Usually the the fan keeps running and the power LED slowly blinks in my case.

Answer (score 1):

See [When is my game save uploaded to the cloud?](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live/game-saves-in-the-cloud/cloud-save-games) where Microsoft outlines exactly what happens. It talks about the whole process, the part specifically related to your quesiton is:

"In a hurry to turn off your console?

Don’t worry! You can turn off your console before a game save is uploaded to the cloud. When you turn off your console, your console stays in low power mode until the game save is uploaded to the cloud (that is, as long as the console has power and is connected to the Internet)."

Wanted to answer with this detail directly from Microsoft, as the existing answers sounded somewhat speculative.